# Inequality in inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, inner-products

Given $V$ an inner product space with norm $(‖v‖_V)^2$=$∫_Ω(v^2 (x)+|∇v|^2 )dx$. Prove that

> $$(∫_Ω(|v||w|+|∇v||∇w|)dx)^2 ≤ ∫_Ω(|v|^2+|∇v|^2 )dx ∫_Ω(|w|^2+|∇w|^2 )dx=(‖v‖_V)^2(‖w‖_V)^2.$$

Any idea to prove this inequality??

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality) applied to $|v|$ and $|w|$ in your specific inner-product space. [It can be proved generically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof). Another standard way is to observe that the quadratic $\|x+ty\|^2$ in $t\in\mathbb{R}$ must have nonpositive discriminant, since it is nonnegative on $\mathbb{R}$. This is for the real case. Do the same trick in the complex case, but consider $\|x+te^{i\theta}y\|^2$ for any, or the appropriate, $\theta$.